# Why getting a preload box for a img tag?

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting a preload box for a img tag from the code below.

```html
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
  load()
  }, false); 
 function grab(){
      var urlsource = document.getElementById("image").value="";
    return urlsource.length > 0;
       
      }
 function load(){
   var imgurl = document.getElementById("image").value;  
      document.getElementById("replace").src=imgurl;
   return imgurl.length > 0;
  }
</script>
<style>
div.output {
height: 200px;
width: 200px; }
img#replace {
    display: none;
 }
img#replace[src]{
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<textarea id="image" onload="grab();" onkeyUp="load();" onkeyPress="load();"></textarea><br>
<a id="demo1" href="https://www.google.co.nz/">
<div class="output">
<img id="replace"/>
</div>
</a>
</body>
```

[image]

How the preload image can be removed while keeping the DOMContentloaded event? Thanks very much!

Comment: Just FWIW, `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ load() }, false);` could be just `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);`

Comment: Thank you! But this will remove the image in the div when I 'go back' from the landing page.

Comment: No, it does **exactly** the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know:) I now found out the mistake that I made. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `<img/>` must have a `src`. If it does not, it's treated as broken.

Give it a `src`, even if that means creating a 1x1 transparent GIF pixel.

```
<img id="replace" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" />
```

EDIT: On closer inspection, it seems that your code is immediately running when the document has loaded, with the code effectively reading:

```
image.src = ""; // because the textarea is empty
```

Of course, this is not a valid image, but it is still *an* image, so it appears as a broken one. You may want to add an `onerror` event to the image to hide it if it fails to load.

```
<img id="replace" onerror="this.removeAttribute('src');" />
```

(This should work because of your CSS hiding source-less images)